# Why do I get a warning of ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’ when I read numbers from a file in C?

Tags: c, file

I would like to read from a file (.txt) two columns in C. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

FILE *f;
int t[160], i, k=0;
double omega[160];

f = fopen("data.txt", "r");

while(!feof(f)){
               fscanf(f, "%d %lf", t, omega); 
               k++;
               }

for (i = 0; i < k; i++) printf("%d %lf\n", t[i], omega[i]);

return 0;
}
```

When I compile the program I get the following error message:

```
average.c: In function ‘main’:
average.c:14:10: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute    warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
    fscanf(f, "%d %lf", t, omega);
          ^
```

How can I deal with this problem? Any help would be appreciated !
Thank you!

a

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, by not ignoring the return value, I'd guess.

Note that `fscanf()` (like `scanf()` and `sscanf()`) returns the number of successful conversions it did. This is very useful so that you can know that your variables really contain the read-in data.

If you *really* want to ignore the value, cast the call to `(void)`:

```
(void) fscanf(f, "%d%lf", t, omega);
```

*However* your code is strangely organized; the inner `fscanf()` call is not needed and should be removed and the first one has the wrong arguments.

The loop should be:

```
while(fscanf(f, "%d %lf", t + k, omega + k) == 2)
{
   k++; 
}
```

Here I use `t + k` as shorter way of writing `&t[k]` (and the same with `omega`).

You should *not* use `feof()` like you do in your edited question: that's just wrong. The use of `feof()` is *after*  a read has failed, to figure out if it maybe failed because the input file ended. There's no need to use it like you do, `fscanf()` will fail, and thus return something else than `2`, on end of file.

Comment: I think OP wanted to do `while(fscanf(f, "%d%lf", t, &omega[k])==2)`

Comment: Thank you unwind for your answer. What is the best manner so to read from a file in C? I do not have an other method! Could you tell me please? thanks!

Comment: unwind @GrijeshChauhan I have edited the program using feof but I get always the same result. Furthermore, when I add k to t and omega in the file reading loop nothing do change! Any help please? Thanks!

Comment: The spaces are not necessary. `scanf` uses whitespace as a cue to break multi-character input and automatically skips whitespace (including newline) when applicable. If you were reading single characters separated by whitespace using `%c`, then you would need the spaces.

Comment: With GCC 4.9.2 running under Ubuntu 15.04, at least, casting the result to (void) does not work; the warning persists.